# May the LORD reward you for your kindness

Tags: translation

I want to translate [this sentence](http://www.allaboutgod.com/truth-topics/kindness.htm) into Italian:

> May the LORD reward you for your kindness.

My attempt:

> Possa Dio ricompensarti per la tua gentilezza.

Is my translation correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, for me the translation is correct.

Comment: Sì, è giusta. Credo sia anche possibile dire: "Possa il Signore ricompensarti per la tua gentilezza".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While in English you must double the pronouns (you/your), in Italian they *feel* redundant. I'd better prefer this translation:

> Possa Dio ricompensare la tua gentilezza

Comment: I looked the link you sent, it seems that Ruth is talking to her sisters-in-law. So the translation should be: **Possa Dio ricompensare la vostra gentilezza** (who knows why, in the italian translation of the Bible it reads **che l'Eterno sia buono con voi**)

Comment: Which Italian translation? There are dozens of them. [BibleGateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ruth%201%3A8&version=CEI;LND;NR1994;NR2006) alone gives no less than four Italian translations. Anyway, all of them mentions *il Signore sia buono* or *usi bontà*, so perhaps the English version given above is not too faithful to the Hebrew original. Also, King James Version gives «the Lord deal kindly with you, as ye have dealt with the dead, and with me».